# AngularJS login logout button need refresh to change

Tags: angularjs

Here is my `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Koupon - Index</title>
    <!-- meta info -->
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Koupon HTML5 Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Koupon - Premiun HTML5 Template for Coupons Website">
    <meta name="author" content="Dark Cyber" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap_responsive.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome styles (icons) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font_awesome.css">
    <!-- Main Template styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- IE 8 Fallback -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

    <!-- Your custom styles (blank file) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="rentalkika">





    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////MAIN HEADER///////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->
    <header class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo-small.png" alt="logo" title="logo" class="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                    <div class="flexnav-menu-button" id="flexnav-menu-button">Menu</div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flexnav" id="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layanan</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#sewa_mobil">Sewa Mobil</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Shuttle</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="features-typography.html">Paket Wisata</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="blog-sidebar-right.html">Blog</a>
                            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tertarik menjadi mitra kami?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <!-- LOGIN REGISTER LINKS -->
                    <ul class="login-register" ng-controller="LoginController">
                    
                        <li ng-show="!isLoggedIn"><a class="popup-text" href="#login-dialog" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top"><i class="icon-signin"></i>Sign in</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="isLoggedIn"><a class="popup-text" href="#" ng-click="logout()"><i class="icon-signout"></i>Sign out</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li><a href="#register"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Sign up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- LOGIN REGISTER LINKS CONTENT -->
    <div id="login-dialog" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog clearfix">
        <i class="icon-signin dialog-icon"></i>
        <h3>Member Login</h3>
        <h5>Welcome back, friend. Login to get started</h5>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="dialog-form" ng-submit="handleLogin()" ng-controller="LoginController">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="yourUsername" ng-model="login.username" class="span12">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="My secret password" ng-model="login.password" class="span12">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox">Remember me
                </label>
                <div class="control-group error" ng-show="error">
                <span class="error help-block">
                 {{ error }}
                </span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="dialog-alt-links">
            <li><a class="popup-text" href="#register-dialog" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Not member yet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="popup-text" href="#password-recover-dialog" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Forgot password</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="password-recover-dialog" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog clearfix">
        <i class="icon-retweet dialog-icon"></i>
        <h3>Password Recovery</h3>
        <h5>Fortgot your password? Don't worry we can deal with it</h5>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="dialog-form">
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="span12">
                <input type="submit" value="Request new password" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LOGIN REGISTER LINKS CONTENT -->
    
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////END MAIN HEADER////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->


<!-- //// START PAGE CONTENT -->

 <div ng-view>
    
   </div>

<!-- END PAGE CONTENT /// -->



    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////MAIN FOOTER////////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->

    <footer class="main">
        <div class="footer-top-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-wrap">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="logo" class="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h5>Get it Anywhere</h5>
                        <p>Ultrices varius semper laoreet molestie purus euismod fames odio volutpat eleifend turpis nec cras quam litora dignissim curae lacus platea sociis mauris hendrerit sed fringilla dignissim cum mi amet orci</p>
                        <ul class="list list-app-download">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="icon-windows box-icon" title="Get Windows Phone App" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="icon-apple box-icon" title="Get iPhone App" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="icon-android box-icon" title="Get Android App" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h5>Koupon on Twitter</h5>
                        <!-- START TWITTER -->
                        <div class="twitter-ticker" id="twitter-ticker"></div>
                        <!-- END TWITTER -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h5>Recent News</h5>
                        <ul class="list post-list">
                            <li class="post-thumb">
                                <h5 class="title"><a href="#">Gravida porttitor vulputate</a></h5><small>05 August, 2013</small>
                                <p class="post-desciption">Dignissim phasellus magnis mus duis nisl ut lacus vehicula velit</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="post-thumb">
                                <h5 class="title"><a href="#">A duis</a></h5><small>29 July, 2013</small>
                                <p class="post-desciption">Class augue curae accumsan tempor semper id integer adipiscing mattis</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-wrap">
                <div class="span3">
                    <h5>About Koupon</h5>
                    <p>Tellus auctor sem sociosqu cras cursus vitae erat aliquam adipiscing iaculis suscipit curabitur hac hac congue netus integer ridiculus volutpat varius suspendisse velit venenatis facilisi velit quis volutpat enim ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h5>Company</h5>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Investors</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h5>For Business</h5>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Runnig a Deal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accept Payments</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Referral Program</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Developers/API</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Merchant Terms</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h5>Get Help</h5>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customer Support</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Statement</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <h5>Keep in touch</h5>
                    <p>Mauris mus tortor leo augue non sociosqu ridiculus sagittis odio</p>
                    <ul class="list list-social">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-facebook box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Facebook"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-twitter box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Twitter"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-flickr box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Flickr"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-linkedin box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Linkedin"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-tumblr box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tumblr"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////END MAIN  FOOTER///////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->

    <!-- Scripts queries -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nivo_slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flexnav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/magnific.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tweet.min.js"></script>
     
  <!--   
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    -->
    
    <script src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wilto_slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mediaelement.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fitvids.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mail.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  
    <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I define 2 LoginController in login dialog and login link

Here is my `app.js`

```js
........
........

   
rentalkika.controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, sessionService){
$scope.login = { username: "", password: "" };
if(sessionService.get('sessionToken') != null){
$scope.isLoggedIn = true; 
}else {
$scope.isLoggedIn = false;
}

$scope.handleLogin = function () {
 
 //authService.login($scope);
 
 
 var configLogin = {
  params: {
   username: $scope.login.username,
   password: $scope.login.password  
  },
  headers: {
   'X-Parse-Application-Id' : 'xxxx',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   
  }
 }

 $http.get('http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/login', configLogin).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  $.magnificPopup.close();
  sessionService.set('isLoggedIn', 'yes');
  sessionService.set('role', response.data.role_name);
  sessionService.set('sessionToken', response.data.sessionToken);
  $scope.isLoggedIn = true; 
  $location.path('/dashboard');
 }, function (error){
  $scope.error = error.data.error;
 });
 
 
}

$scope.logout = function () {
 sessionService.destroy('isLoggedIn'); 
 sessionService.destroy('role'); 
 sessionService.destroy('sessionToken');
 $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
 
}


});

rentalkika.factory('sessionService', function () {

var sessionService = {};

sessionService.set = function (key, value) {
 return sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
};

sessionService.get = function (key) {
 return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
};
 
sessionService.destroy = function (key) {
 return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
}; 

return sessionService;

});
```

What I want is when I successfully submit login, the sign in button will change to sign out button, then vice versa when I successfully click sign out button.

My problem is the button sign in will change to sign out after I refresh browser.

Is something missing or wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can Define both HTML elements and use angular `ng-show` to show each depending on the variable.For example `hasNotsignedIn` like this:

```
<input ng-show="hasNotsignedIn" type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary">

<input ng-show="!hasNotsignedIn" type="button" value="Sign out" class="btn btn-primary">
```

then Set the variable in the controller by default `$scope.hasNotsignedIn=true;` 
When you post the form then `$scope.hasNotsignedIn=false;`
and  on click of sign out button set `$scope.hasNotsignedIn=true;`

Then do it like this

```
rentalkika.controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, sessionService){
$scope.login = { username: "", password: "" };
$scope.hasNotsignedIn = true;  //Changeed
if(sessionService.get('sessionToken') != null){

}else {

}

$scope.handleLogin = function () {

    //authService.login($scope);


    var configLogin = {
        params: {
            username: $scope.login.username,
            password: $scope.login.password     
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id' : 'xxxx',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        }
    }

    $http.get('http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/login', configLogin).then(function (response) {

        $scope.hasNotsignedIn = false; //changed


        console.log(response.data);
        $.magnificPopup.close();
        sessionService.set('isLoggedIn', 'yes');
        sessionService.set('role', response.data.role_name);
        sessionService.set('sessionToken', response.data.sessionToken);
        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;   
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }, function (error){
        $scope.error = error.data.error;
    });


}

$scope.logout = function () {
    sessionService.destroy('isLoggedIn');   
    sessionService.destroy('role'); 
    sessionService.destroy('sessionToken');
    $scope.hasNotsignedIn = true;  //changed

}


});
```

Comment: which controller? because I have `LoginNavController` and `LoginController` in sign in and sing out button in LoginNavController while login function in LoginController.

Comment: Let me show you in the edit but an gonna show you in the functions

Comment: Well in LoginController it would work there But according to your design YOu have two controllers for login and logout?

Comment: You just needed one controller called authentication to do that.The design is not good that is why you are facing such problems.

Comment: According to what I see there is no need for LoginNavController

Comment: Now You have to move the value from one controller to another which can be expensive for you

Comment: now I define `LoginController` twice in login form it self and login link. and doesn't work. would you like to correct my code?

Comment: Let me look att it